# user vs. root in node and npm installations

Tags: node.js, angularjs, root, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm experiencing problems trying to install node and npm apps.
Typically trying to setup new apps with yo and generator-angular.

I've installed yeoman (sudo npm install -g yo)
I've installed generator-angular (sudo npm install -g generator-angular).

However when trying to create a new app with the generator I get rights issues.
yo angular temp (for example).

When investigating, I don't understand why the .npm folder in my user directory has some folders created as the root user.

I'm on mac, Mavericks.

Is there a specific way to install node and the rest. In terms of sudo / root / user priviledges ?

I've completely reinstalled node, by downlading 0.10.26 form the nodejs.org website.

Comment: The `.npm` directory is just a cache, nothing more.  You don't need it... you can nuke it if you want.

Comment: The only solution I have found in getting it working, sometimes, is doing a sudo rm -rf ~/.npm, but to me that doesn't make sense to have to do sudo in the ~ folder. I'm concerned i've installed things incorrectly somehow and the rights are getting screwed up somehow

Comment: Typically, anything installed globally requires sudo/root.  Anything not installed globally doesn't.  If you stick to that, you should be fine.